# Go: how to convert struct to []byte?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to use "appengine/memcache" to store data in the cache,
memcache.Item's Value field is []byte

how do I convert a struct to []byte for storing it ?

for example:

```
type Link struct {
    Files []string
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the memcache.Codec type, this can be used to convert memcache items. The appengine/memcache package has two codecs already prepared, memcache.Gob and memcache.JSON. You use these codecs instead of the direct call to store and retrieve items from the cache, for example like this for a gob encoded item:

```
    item := &memcache.Item{
        Key:    myCacheKey,
        Object: &myLinkVar,
    }
    err := memcache.Gob.Set(context, item)
```

Comment: What is `context` in this example?

Answer (score 3):

The `encoding/gob` package is probably your best option.

You could also use the `encoding/json` package.

If you use `encoding/json` you get the benefit of being able to read the values from languages other than Go.

If you use `encoding/gob` you get more speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gob#Encoder.Encode`:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "encoding/gob"
   "fmt"
)

type link struct {
   Files []string
}

func main() {
   s := link{
      []string{"south", "north"},
   }
   b := new(bytes.Buffer)
   gob.NewEncoder(b).Encode(s)
   // "\x1d\xff\x81\x03\x01\x01\x04link\x01\xff\x82\x00\x01\x01\x01\x05Files\x01\xff\x84\x00\x00\x00\x16\xff\x83\x02\x01\x01\b[]string\x01\xff\x84\x00\x01\f\x00\x00\x11\xff\x82\x01\x02\x05south\x05north\x00"
   fmt.Printf("%q\n", b)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob#Encoder.Encode